# Node.js app works locally, doesn't on digitalocean - Cannot GET

Tags: node.js, express, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I'm trying to run my portfolio site on DigitalOcean and it's working perfectly fine locally but on DO server, I'm getting a Cannot GET error for my about page. All other pages are working just fine. I've double checked all the routes in my app.js and they are perfectly fine and all of the .ejs files are in views folder itself. Please help!

Here is my app.js

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require('express');
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// const ejs = require('ejs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

const allProjects = ["tindog", "dice", "simon", "drumkit"];


app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render("index");
});


app.get("/projects", function(req, res){
   res.render("projects");
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
    res.render("about");
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
   res.render("contact");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log("Server started on port 3000...");
});
```

Comment: For which route you are getting error?

Comment: the about page i.e /about route

Comment: Gut feeling: Maybe your `about.ejs` file has the wrong case in the filename, e.g. `About.ejs` or so. On the server it'll be Linux with case-sensitive filenames, even though on your computer it may be Windows where case doesn't matter.

Comment: I just checked that as well. It's about.ejs

Comment: Are you sure that `about.ejs` exists on the server (not just on your computer)? Maybe it is not committed in Git or accidentally ignored, and when you deploy your application, the file is not part of the deployment even though it exists on your machine...

Comment: Yes, I checked the server as well right now. All the files are exactly the same.

Comment: Bottom line is, the only ways to get this error are: 1) You go to a wrong URL (I guess that's not what's happening), 2) The route path is wrong (which is not the case, according to your code), 3) The _view file_ cannot be found because it either doesn't exist or has a filename that has a different case. - Otherwise it's a bit of a mystery. Can you share the live DO URL and a screenshot (not just text - yes I know SO usually wants text but here a screenshot can convey more information) of the output of `ls -la` in the `views` directory on the server via SSH?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the server via ssh https://linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-44.png  It seems fine according to me...Don't know where exactly is the problem

Comment: May be the rendering is failed. Can you please show the code what you are rendering?

Comment: Sorry couldn't exactly understand by "what you are rendering". Do you want to see the output that I'm getting on the browser? If yes, then here it is https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-45.png

Comment: No. I want to see the code in about.ejs.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-47.png

Comment: Actually it looks all OK! Which makes me think, maybe the code running on your server is not the latest one. If you update an EJS file, you see the effect immediately (in non-cached mode at least), but if you update the actual JS code that runs in the server (for example the `app.js` that defines your routes!) then you have to restart your application on the server. Maybe you added the `/about` route to `app.js` only recently and pushed the new files but didn't restart the app?

Comment: Thank you very much for this!!! I restarted the server and it worked! I'm literally mind blown by the fact that this simple problem was causing this issue and you've guessed it somehow so quickly....Again I thank you from my bottom of my heart!

Comment: @niranjay_30 Did you restart the entire server or just the app? I have the same problem, but I've been restarting the app thinking that should be sufficient. I'll try restarting the server and see what happens.